# Creating AMI for VNC on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, vnc, xfce

I'm trying to create an AMI of an Ubuntu 18.04 EC2 that's configured with VNC.

I've successfully SSH'd into it and connected via a VNC Viewer. I then created an image from the running instance, however launching new instances from this image fails to start VNC again.

**My VNC Setup:**

After SSHing into my instance:

```
sudo apt update
```

```
sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver
```

```
vncserver # then set my password
```

```
vncserver -kill :1
```

Then I set ~/.vnc/xstartup to:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

Then it worked if I did: `sudo chmod +x ~/.vnc/xstartup` and `vncserver`

**Things I tried:**

- Simply launching an EC2 from this image
- Launching an EC2 from this image with the user data:

```
#!/bin/bash
vncserver
```

How can I create a custom AMI so I could launch an EC2 that autostarts a VNC server (or even starts the server after a user data script)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it with crontabs.

After killing the vncserver, I just ran:

```
crontab -e
```

Then chose my preferred editor and added `@reboot vncserver :1` to the file.

From here, creating the image from the EC2 console was as simple as selecting the instance -> actions -> image -> create image.